# "which version" output differently with setting version in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using currently the latest version of PyCharm and python 2.7 (Home brew). I set python version in PyCharm like this:

[image]

However, when I run codes in the same project:

[image]

I get output like this:

[image]

Why is that? And how can I config the right Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you are running an OS command outside an activated virtualenv, probably. I think you can trust the python binary that is interpreting the code is correct. For example, try to import a module that exists only in the environment

Comment: Thanks~ I think this explanation works for me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `which python` to find out which `python` you're using. 
Try this instead:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```